# "I dig my auntie" — what does this mean

Tags: meaning, phrases, slang

My baby has a t-shirt with "I dig my auntie" on it.
What does this mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun

Comment: @Kris Maybe I'm being quite slow, but how is it a pun? Unless the aunt is an archaeologist :)

Comment: @anotherdave That's for another site, it's not relevant on ELU.

Comment: @Kris OK, fair enough. Though if the explanation isn't relevant, the link probably isn't relevant either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To dig* is slang for liking something.  *I dig my auntie* is a hip way of saying *I like my auntie*.

Comment: And *auntie* is a familiar way of saying *aunt*.

Comment: ... and *hip* is slang for *cool*. Which is also kind of slang.

Comment: ... and [all](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/auntie) these [words](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hip) can be [found](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cool) in a [dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dig).

Comment: So why is it on a T-shirt? What's so funny about that? Ask on a relevant site or better on a forum. (What is that emoticon showing the tongue?)